# Java. Что происходит, когда возвращаемое значение не помещается ни в какую переменную?

Tags: java

Вопрос слегка глупый, просто интересно, понятно, что так никто не делает, но все же - это будет жрать ресурсы и т.д?

Например, есть вот такой метод

```
public String getName(){
return name;
}
```

И я где-нибудь его вызываю вот так, без сохранения в переменную

```
getName();
```

Надо так.

```
String s = getName();
```

:D Да, очень глупо получилось, но все же. Что происходит со значением, если оно никуда не делось?

Comment: Оно исчезает так как после вызова функции стек освобождается, и если присвоения не было - память, использованная при вызове идёт прямиком в коллектор мусора (ну или ещё куда в Java по усмотрению коллектора)

Comment: name это поле или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае в области памяти под названием "куча" (там, где создаются вообще все объекты) просто будет создаваться объект типа String. Но к нему не ведет никакой ссылки, соответственно, использовать данный объект мы уже никогда не сможем. Поэтому сборщик мусора при первой же необходимости попросту удалит этот объект из памяти.